# How to get all ip connected in this moment at my server?

Tags: javascript, websocket, server, ip

guys, I have this doubt with websockets in javascript, I want to return the ip's connected to the server and i don't have idea to do it, I only want the ip's, I just want the ones that are connected at the moment.

Here is my server:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
  response.writeHead(404);
  response.end();
});
server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Server is listening on port 8080');
});

wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
  httpServer: server,
  autoAcceptConnections: false
});

function originIsAllowed(origin) {
// put logic here to detect whether the specified origin is allowed.
  return true;
}

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    if (!originIsAllowed(request.origin)) {
  // Make sure we only accept requests from an allowed origin
      request.reject();
      console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' request.origin + ' rejected.');
  return;
}

var connection = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin);
console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection accepted.');
connection.on('message', function(message) {
    if (message.type === 'utf8') {
        console.log('Received Message: ' + message.utf8Data);
        var ipAddress = connection.remoteAddress;
        console.log(ipAddress);
        connection.sendUTF("pablo puta");
    }
    else if (message.type === 'binary') {
        console.log('Received Binary Message of ' + message.binaryData.length + ' bytes');
        connection.sendBytes(message.binaryData);
    }
});
connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Peer ' + connection.remoteAddress + ' disconnected.');
 });
});
```

Please, if you can help me, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can keep an object of ips:

```
var ips={};
connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
  delete ips[connection.remoteAddress];
});
 connection.on('open', function(reasonCode, description) {
    ips[connection.remoteAddress]=true;
});
```

And then somehow response with:

```
Object.keys(ips);
```

to yourself...

(I believe it must be *this* instead of *connection* inside the handlers, but im not an expert in that...)